# Gunicorn does not show Django static files

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I've seen this question asked before but none of the responses have helped.

I'm trying to deploy my Python3/Django project to AWS with gunicorn + nginx. The project name is vicver, and when I try to run

```
 $ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 vicver.wsgi
```

I can see my site on the AWS public IP port 8000 but without any `js/css` or images. When I do the same with the `runserver` command it works fine.

My settings.py contains the following paths:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'vicver/static') ]
```

And here's a screenshot of the terminal
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N76Bo.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It works when you run `runserver` command because you're in development mode. But when you want to deploy your application to production env, you should use some of these options to serve static files [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Normally I use Nginx to serve static files, and create a reverse proxy to proxy other requests into the app which served by Gunicorn. You can take a look on this [Deploying django application](https://medium.com/@_christopher/deploying-my-django-app-to-a-real-server-part-ii-f0c277c338f4) to serve your app by using Gunicorn too.

Answer (score 0):

You can not serve your static and media file in the production mode(Debug=False). The best way to serve statics and media with this structure is by using Nginx.
First, you need to collect your statics using the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then you need to edit your "nginx.conf" file using the following codes. Be careful to replace "/usr/src/app/" with your project path.

```
server {

    listen 80 backlog=2048;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}
    location /static/ {
        alias   /usr/src/app/vicver/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias  /usr/src/app/vicver/media/;
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: I have tried everything from about a 100 posts on the net, and no matter what I do, my production site will only work with DEBUG=True.